# How to get current item on Dropdownlist for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My design code :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID ="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"  AutoPostBack ="true" CssClass="ddl" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Products.aspx?catId=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
```

In database category table:

```
Book 1
Movie 2
Game 3
Music 4
```

Book is always current item of drop down list. when i select others, their pages load but dropdownlist's current value is book and i can'response book's page.

Comment: Where is the post back funciton ="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: Ups sorry, i edit it...

Comment: check page_load event if (!ispostback ){}

Comment: Is this function supposed to be redirecting to a different page or to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing a redirect, this means your page is being loaded again with the default binding, making first item selected by default, subscribe to the data bound event and perform selection based on the query string parameter.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList  OnDataBound="DropDownList1_DataBound" ...
```

**C#**

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack){
     string selectedValue = Request.QueryString["catId"];
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
       DropDownList1.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: that way he keeps queering the DB and rebinding over and over again

Comment: he doesn't need to, from what I gathered it's a master page control

Comment: even though, he is using a `SqlDataSource` and doing a redirect!!

Comment: Thank you, i can load it. But now when i open web site if i select firstly book(first item) i can't response if i select others and after that select first item i can response.

Comment: This is because index didn't change, you can insert a placeholder item at the top of the list, like "Select category"

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the list binds with the `SqlDataSource` on every postback so you are always getting the value of the first item.

To make sure that that's the problem, change the order of the select to DESC and see if you're always getting the last item.

change you're SQL to

`SELECT * FROM [Categories] ORDER BY CategoryId DESC`

And see if you're always getting `4`.

If that's the problem then you need to bind the list by code always within page load like below:

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: I think you got this wrong, as the OP says: "when i select others, their pages load but dropdownlist's current value is book", he gets the selected value right and after redirect the dropdown is back to first item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approach
Either move the dropdown populating code in the Page_Load and encapsulate the code with

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //your code
}
```

or

```
<%
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{ %>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<%}
%>
```

Comment: you're missing `<% %>`, your answer doesn't make sense without them

Comment: @Ted its just a code snippet. anyway i have edited that

Comment: you're good to go syntactically, but what happens when his page posts back and `DropDownList1` cannot find `SqlDataSource1` anymore?

Comment: This won't do any good, as the source will be unavailable on post back, The Select method of the SqlDataSource is called automatically when you call the DataBind method of the page or of a control bound to the data source control. Moreover, Data binding events are raised after the control's PreRender event, which occurs after the page's PreRender event. (This applies to controls whose DataSourceID property is set declaratively. Otherwise the event happens when you call the control's DataBind method.)

Comment: thats why i suggested changes in view as second approach where we have made more changes to fit the requirement. but in first approach he just have to add his data binding code in the Page_Load event handler inside if(!Page.IsPostBack){ //code }

Comment: I think his problem is not with page load, he is mentioning that the redirect is ok, but first item gets selected (which is the expected behavior as he didn't update the selected item based on the query string value).